# Calling .getJSON more than once

Tags: javascript, json, callback

```
var name, logo, streaming,twitchfeed;
var users = ["freecodecamp", "medrybw", "geoffstorbeck",
"terakilobyte", "habathcx", "robotCaleb",
"thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff","boonyzarc"
];

function getInfo(){

 users.forEach(function(user) {
  var channelURL = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + user + '?callback=?';
  var streamURL = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + user + '?callback=?';

$.getJSON(channelURL, function(channel) {
$.getJSON(streamURL, function(stream) {
  if (stream.stream === null) {
    streaming = '<span class="label label-danger pull-right label-rawle offline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>';
  } else {
    streaming = '<span class="label label-success pull-right label-rawle online"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>';
  }
  twitchfeed = channel.url;
  console.log(twitchfeed);
  name = channel.display_name;

  if (channel.logo === null) {
    channel.logo = 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/186/382004453_f4b2772254.jpg';
  }
  logo = '<img src="' + channel.logo + '" class="logo">';

  $('#person').append('<div class="user" id="' + name + '">');
  $('#' + name).append(logo + '<a href="'+twitchfeed+'" TARGET="_blank">' + '<span class="name">' + name + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>' + streaming);
  $('#' + name).append('<div class="topic">' + stream.stream.channel.status + '</div>');
});


 // what happens when tabs are clicked
$(function() {

  // 'all' tab
  $('#all').click(function() {

    $('#all').addClass('active');
    $('#online').removeClass('active');
    $('#offline').removeClass('active');

    $(".user").show();
  });
});

// 'online' tab
$('#online').click(function() {

  $('#all').removeClass('active');
  $('#online').addClass('active');
  $('#offline').removeClass('active');

  $(".user").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children(".offline").length < 1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});

// 'offline' tab
$('#offline').click(function() {
  $('#all').removeClass('active');
  $('#online').removeClass('active');
  $('#offline').addClass('active');

  $(".user").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children(".offline").length < 1) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
 });
});
});


}

//Trying to add a user
/*$('#submit-rawle-button').click(function(){
var $newUser = $('#newUser').val();
if(users.indexOf($newUser)==-1)
  {
    users.push($newUser);
  }
getInfo();
});*/

getInfo();
```

I'm new to using JSON and the jquery $.getJSON function. If I pull all of the code out of the getInfo function and just call it once I have no problem. But maybe it's my lack of understanding but I thought if I put all that into a function. Then later I could add a button that after adding a new user to the user array. I could call the getInfo function again and it would give me a new JSON object updated with the new user that was added. However, instead I just get back empty objects. Will someone explain to me either why getInfo can't be called more than once or what my coding error is to not be getting updating JSON object.

Comment: Question first, code second

Answer (score 0):

The users.forEach is not waiting for the ajax calls to finish.I think the term is AJAX is asynchronous and the forEach is synchronous.

Keep this in mind every time you use ajax. I changed the code a bit so that it won't try to go to the next user UNTIL the second getJSON has finished.
There has to be a more elegant way to do this. I also recommend looking in to [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) it will come in handy in the future. Hope this helps.

```
var name, logo, streaming, twitchfeed;
var users = ["freecodecamp", "medrybw", "geoffstorbeck",
    "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "robotCaleb",
    "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff", "boonyzarc"
];

function getInfo() {

    var usersTotal = users.length;
    var userCounter = 0;


    function getNextUser() {

        if (usersTotal > userCounter) {

            var user = users[userCounter];
            var channelURL = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + user + '?callback=?';
            var streamURL = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + user + '?callback=?';

            $.getJSON(channelURL, function (channel) {
                $.getJSON(streamURL, function (stream) {
                    if (stream.stream === null) {
                        streaming = '<span class="label label-danger pull-right label-rawle offline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>';
                    } else {
                        streaming = '<span class="label label-success pull-right label-rawle online"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>';
                    }
                    twitchfeed = channel.url;
                    console.log(twitchfeed);
                    name = channel.display_name;

                    if (channel.logo === null) {
                        channel.logo = 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/186/382004453_f4b2772254.jpg';
                    }
                    logo = '<img src="' + channel.logo + '" class="logo">';

                    $('#person').append('<div class="user" id="' + name + '">');
                    $('#' + name).append(logo + '<a href="' + twitchfeed + '" TARGET="_blank">' + '<span class="name">' + name + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>' + streaming);
                    $('#' + name).append('<div class="topic">' + stream.stream.channel.status + '</div>');


                });

                // what happens when tabs are clicked
                $(function () {

                    // 'all' tab
                    $('#all').click(function () {

                        $('#all').addClass('active');
                        $('#online').removeClass('active');
                        $('#offline').removeClass('active');

                        $(".user").show();
                    });
                });

// 'online' tab
                $('#online').click(function () {

                    $('#all').removeClass('active');
                    $('#online').addClass('active');
                    $('#offline').removeClass('active');

                    $(".user").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).children(".offline").length < 1) {
                            $(this).show();
                        } else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
                });

// 'offline' tab
                $('#offline').click(function () {
                    $('#all').removeClass('active');
                    $('#online').removeClass('active');
                    $('#offline').addClass('active');

                    $(".user").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).children(".offline").length < 1) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        } else {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        }

        userCounter++;
        getNextUser();

    }

    getNextUser();
}

//Trying to add a user
/*$('#submit-rawle-button').click(function(){
 var $newUser = $('#newUser').val();
 if(users.indexOf($newUser)==-1)
 {
 users.push($newUser);
 }
 getInfo();
 });*/

getInfo();
```

Comment: In the getNextUser function. Since my array equals 9 and the userCounter is 0. It never actually enters the while loop, so I don't append anything to person . I thought maybe it was suppose to be greater than instead but that sends me into a infinite loop. I've linked my codepen in case the code I didn't post is needed but I thought they were separate things so I left them off here.

http://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/adNMKM

Comment: I updated the code since I messed up a bit of the logic. I tried it on your code pend and it appends some of the users, hopefully this will take you one step closer.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.